# How to ignore @2x images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code below to populate an array with images:

```
NSString *fileName;
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 1; i < 285; i++) {
        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation HD1.2 png sequence/HD1.2_%d.png", i];
        [myArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
        NSLog(@"Loaded image: %d", i);
    }
```

In my resources folder i have @2x versions of each of these images. Is there a way (programmatically) that I can ignore the @2x images on retina devices and populate the array with the non-@2x images?

**EDIT 1:**

I've edited my code to use `NSData`:

```
  myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 1; i < 285; i++) {
        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation HD1.2 png sequence/HD1.2_%d.png", i];
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
        UIImage *regularImage = [UIImage imageWithData:fileData];
        [myArray addObject:regularImage];
    }

falling.animationImages = MYArray;
```

This is crashing my app with the error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`. Am i using the NSData object wrong?

Comment: What happens if you just delete them?

Comment: That would work fine but i don't want to delete them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the question amounts to "How do I bypass the automatic @2x image loading?"

You need to take a path it can't follow. You could pass the contents of each file using `NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` to `UIImage imageWithData:` This way, `imageWithData` won't know where the data came from, let alone that there's a 2x version.

Comment: That's exactly what the question amounts to. I'll try that out now and come back...

Comment: I've edited the OP. The app crashes when i try to add the image to the array stating the object is nil.

Comment: You probably need a full path. Assuming it's in your application bundle, use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:]` to get it.

Comment: You probably got a `nil` from the `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:`. And you probably got an error back, too. It's worth learning to check that functions are succeeding. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the NSData technique should work, but you need to get the path from your bundle, you can't just give the filename as a string like that.

Try:

```
filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation HD1.2 png sequence/HD1.2_%d.png", i] ofType:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
//This string will have @"@2x.png"

NSString *verificationString = [myString substringFromIndex:[myString length] - 7];
if(![verificationString isEqualToString:@"@2x.png"]) 
{
    //NOT EQUAL...
}
```

Comment: `isEqualTo` is not a valid selector. Can you tell me the equivalent? I have a feeling this will simply load no images into the array...

Comment: [verificationString isEqualToString:@"@2x.png"]